# OSX Apache : allow execution of shell command for PHP script - include path

Tags: php, macos, apache, shell, path

I am running a website on OSX server, that needs to execute `pdftotext`, which is installed in `/usr/local/bin`. However, there seems to be an issue with the command not being in the Apache path.

I first confirmed that I can execute shell scripts. `<?php shell_exec('whoami'); ?>` returns `_www`.

However, when I run the following :

```
 $cmd = 'has pdftotext 2>&- || echo 1';
 $out = shell_exec($cmd);
 echo $out;
```

it returns "1" meaning it cannot access the command.

The same command run from terminal returns nothing (I can access the program without any issue).

When I run `shell_exec('env'."2>&1")` `/usr/local/bin` is indeed not in the path. Where do I set it for Apache2 on OSX Mountain Lion Server ?

### UPDATE

See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer as to how to modify the Apache PATH here: https://gist.github.com/thebigdog/5208619

I needed to modify `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`, adding

```
<key>PATH</key>
<string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
```

to the existing `<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>` definition. So in the end it looked like this:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
    <key>SERVER_INSTALL_PATH_PREFIX</key>
    <string>/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot</string>
    <key>XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
```

Once I restarted the Apache server, the path was added and the shell command was executed properly.